# Get substring from parenthesis JAVA

Tags: java

**No full solutions please!**

> > Given a string that contains a single pair of parenthesis, compute recursively a new string made of only of the parenthesis and their
> >     contents, so "xyz(abc)123" yields "(abc)".
>
> parenBit("xyz(abc)123") → "(abc)"
>
> parenBit("x(hello)") → "(hello)"
>
> parenBit("(xy)1") → "(xy)"

My solution doesn't work

```
public String parenBit(String str) {
        char c;
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
            c = str.charAt(i);
            if(c == '('){
                start = i;

            } if(c == '('){
                end = i;
                return str.substring(start, end);
            }

        }

return "andrew";
}
```

It doesnt print out anything. Why?

Comment: The second if should be `if(c == ')')`

Comment: The assignment says that you must write a *recursive* method to do this. Your solution does not use recursion (= the method should call itself).

Comment: Your solution returns on first occurrence of `'('` with empty string.
Fix: change `} if(c == '('){` to `} else if (c==')') {`

Comment: @Jesper, ah! Dang it. I'll try recursion now. Just a question, which is more efficient? This or recursion?

Comment: A non-recursive solution will probably be more efficient. But if this is an exercise to learn how to use recursion, whether it's efficient or not is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your second if condition. You are checking for ( not )

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String parenBit(String str) {
    char c;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
        c = str.charAt(i);
        if(c == '('){
            start = i;

        } if(c == ')'){
            end = i;
            return str.substring(start + 1, end);
        }

    }

    return "";
}
```

Explanation of changes:

First, the second if is changed to `if (c == ')')` to check for a closing parenthesis. Secondly, the `start` variable is off by one, so I added 1 to it. Lastly, I don't think you should return `andrew` if no parentheses are found. So I changed it to return an empty string.